# The marginals of a truncated multinomial are truncated binomials?

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, truncation

The multinomial distribution for a vector $\vec x$ of non-negative integers assigns a probability of:

$$f(\vec x) = n!\prod_i p_i^{x_i}/x_i!$$

to every vector $\vec x$ of non-negative integers in the range $0\le x_i \le n$ and satisfying $\sum_i x_i = n$, where $0 \le p_i \le 1$ are parameters with $\sum_i p_i = 1$, and $n$ is a positive integer.

Given vectors $\vec a, \vec b$ of non-negative integers with $\vec a \le \vec b$ component-wise, we can define a truncated multinomial distribution by:

$$g(\vec x) \propto f(\vec x)$$

for $\vec a \le \vec x \le \vec b$ component-wise, and $g(\vec x) = 0$ otherwise. The proportionality constant ensures normalization.

It is known that the marginals of $f(\vec x)$ are binomial distributions (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122915/5536).

What are the marginals of $g(\vec x)$? Are they truncated binomials?

Comment: The problem as formulated do not make sense! maybe you made an error ... You forgot one condition, that $\sum_i \vec{x}_i = n$, or else the probability mass function will be zero. But we also have $\sum_i \vec{a}_i \le \sum_i \vec{x}_i \le \sum_i \vec{b}_i$, and you can soon conclude that the only vector contained in the interval and with positive probability, is $\vec{x}$ itself.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen *"and you can soon conclude that the only vector contained in the interval and with positive probability, is $\vec x$  itself."* How do you conclude that?

Comment: Because we can assume that $\sum_i \vec{a}_i =\sum_i \vec{b}_i = n$, and then the assumed componentwise inequality does the rest.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I do *not* assume that $\sum_i a_i = \sum_i b_i = n$.

Comment: I see now. I don't think the marginals will be truncated binomials. The summation over multiple indices get complicated, inhibiting such a solution.